# TCP bidirectional communication between c# and android

Tags: android, tcp, bidirectional

I try to connect a Pc with and Android device via TCPp using the eneter library

When I send data from the android device to the PC, data is transferred and answer back to android is received immediately but I get problems transfering data from PC to the android device

With the following code the PC is sending the data to itself because I receive the data on the OnMessageReceived procedure of the C# code not in the android

```
    public NCProgram()
    {
        aReceiverFactory    = new DuplexTypedMessagesFactory();
        myReceiver  = aReceiverFactory.CreateDuplexTypedMessageReceiver<MyResponse, MyRequest>();
        mySender = aReceiverFactory.CreateDuplexTypedMessageSender<MyResponse, MyRequest>();

        // Subscribe to handle messages.
        myReceiver.MessageReceived += OnMessageReceived;
        mySender.ResponseReceived += OnResponseReceived;

        // Create TCP messaging.
        IMessagingSystemFactory aMessaging = new TcpMessagingSystemFactory();
        IDuplexInputChannel anInputChannel = aMessaging.CreateDuplexInputChannel("tcp://192.168.173.1:6060/");
        IDuplexOutputChannel anOutputChannel = aMessaging.CreateDuplexOutputChannel("tcp://192.168.173.1:6060/");

        // Attach the input channel and start to listen to messages.
        myReceiver.AttachDuplexInputChannel(anInputChannel);

        // Attach output channel to the sender and be able to send
        // request messages and receive responses.
        mySender.AttachDuplexOutputChannel(anOutputChannel);

        m_TexteRebut = "Comunicació establerta";
    }

    public void Enviar()
    {
        MyRequest aRequestMessage = new MyRequest();
        aRequestMessage.Text = m_Texte_Enviar;
        mySender.SendRequestMessage(aRequestMessage);
    }
```

If I don't use the the outputchannel and I send the message as if it was an answer to a communication from the android device, then the data are transferred to the android device but sometimes it takes one second, sometimes a few ones and sometimes 20 or 30 seconds.

```
    public NCProgram()
    {
        aReceiverFactory    = new DuplexTypedMessagesFactory();
        myReceiver  = aReceiverFactory.CreateDuplexTypedMessageReceiver<MyResponse, MyRequest>();
        //mySender = aReceiverFactory.CreateDuplexTypedMessageSender<MyResponse, MyRequest>();

        // Subscribe to handle messages.
        myReceiver.MessageReceived += OnMessageReceived;
        //mySender.ResponseReceived += OnResponseReceived;

        // Create TCP messaging.
        IMessagingSystemFactory aMessaging = new TcpMessagingSystemFactory();
        IDuplexInputChannel anInputChannel = aMessaging.CreateDuplexInputChannel("tcp://192.168.173.1:6060/");
        //IDuplexOutputChannel anOutputChannel = aMessaging.CreateDuplexOutputChannel("tcp://192.168.173.1:6060/");

        // Attach the input channel and start to listen to messages.
        myReceiver.AttachDuplexInputChannel(anInputChannel);

        // Attach output channel to the sender and be able to send
        // request messages and receive responses.
        //mySender.AttachDuplexOutputChannel(anOutputChannel);

        m_TexteRebut = "Comunicació establerta";
    }

    public void Enviar()
    {
        MyRequest aRequestMessage = new MyRequest();
        aRequestMessage.Text = m_Texte_Enviar;
        myReceiver.SendResponseMessage(IPAddress,aRequestMessage);
    }
```

Any advice on how to solve the communication from PC to android device will be appreciated